# Android search interface vs. simply getting search query

Tags: android

I'm trying to implement search into my app and have trouble understanding the difference between these two methods. Why is it that we have to define a search configuration (described here: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/search/search-dialog.html), add a bunch of meta-data to the manifest, and have a separate activity just for search, when we can treat it like any other TextView, grab it's text, and query the database with that? Is there any advantage to the former method, or any disadvantage to the latter? In my mind directly getting the text and doing my own stuff off of that seems a lot easier, especially when after dealing with the search interface I'll still need to get the query from the intent and perform the actual search with that. Am I missing something here? Thanks!

Here's what I mean by directly getting the search query (without using the search interface):

```
@Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
    MenuItem search = menu.findItem(R.id.action_search);
    SearchView searchView = (SearchView) search.getActionView();
    searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
            // Do stuff with query
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
            // Do stuff with newText
            return true;
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have few advantages in working with the "standard" searching feature:

1. The search will look as the user is use to have is "search" boxes on any device. If you design something this will be for all devices. I love to be in the "standard" because in this way for the users is very simple to use it and compatibility over devices is much wider
2. Activity Life Cycle : see [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/search/search-dialog.html#LifeCycle). This a huge advantage.
3. If the Look & Feel fit's with your design you have a lot of other features that are available and checked and working and almost bugles.

Daniel

Comment: With what I'm doing though I'm using the same Search widget. As far as I'm concerned I'm doing absolutely nothing different except for cutting out some steps in the middle and going from search -> android search framework -> my search processing in a different activity to search -> my processing in same activity. I don't think there's any look and feel difference. 

Also, could you please elaborate on how the activity life cycle will affect this?